# c#, Xamarin: execution webRequest.GetResponse() failed

Tags: c#, events, soap, xamarin

I've created a class SoapClient, which created basic functionality for sending simple get and post requests. However, the output yields only 'bingo' and 'System.Net.WebAsyncResult', and doesn't continue after that in the SoapCLient's showDef function. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance... :)

**SoapClient class**

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Android.OS;
namespace Dictionaryv3
{
    public class SoapClient
    {

        private HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        private Handler Dispatcher;

        public delegate void soapDelegate (XmlDocument x);
        public event soapDelegate responseReady;

        public SoapClient() {}



        public void SendGetRequest(String url, String action, string key, string value) {
            Dispatcher = new Handler ();
            url += "/" + action+ "?";

            if (key != null) {
                url+= key+"=" + value;
            }

            webRequest = CreateGetWebRequest(url);
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback (responseReceived), null);
        }

        private void responseReceived(IAsyncResult res) {
            Console.WriteLine ("bingo");
            Console.WriteLine (res.ToString ());
            var result = webRequest.EndGetResponse (res);

            Console.Write("received");
            Console.Write(result.ToString()); 

            Dispatcher.Post (() => {

                Stream responseStream = result.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
                string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
                if(responseReady != null) {
                    responseReady(doc);
                }


            });
        }

        public void SendPostRequest(String url, XmlDocument envelop) {
            Dispatcher = new Handler ();
            webRequest = CreatePostWebRequest(url);
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(envelop, webRequest);
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(responseReceived, null);
        }

        private void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }

        private HttpWebRequest CreateGetWebRequest(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private HttpWebRequest CreatePostWebRequest(String url) {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

    }
}
```

**LookUpActivity**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Dictionaryv3
{
    [Activity (Label = "Dictionary", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class LookUpActivity : Activity
    {

        private Button LookUp;
        private EditText Input;
        private ListView WordView;
        private List<Word> Words = new List<Word>();
        private Button Menu;
        private SoapClient client;


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView( Resource.Layout.Main);

            LookUp = ( Button ) FindViewById ( Resource.Id.lookup);
            Input = (EditText)FindViewById (Resource.Id.input);
            WordView = (ListView)FindViewById (Resource.Id.words);
            Menu = (Button)FindViewById (Resource.Id.menu);
            client = new SoapClient ();
            client.responseReady += showDef;

            Menu.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (this, Menu);

                menu.Inflate (Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
                menu.Show ();

                menu.MenuItemClick += (object send, PopupMenu.MenuItemClickEventArgs args) => {
                    string title = args.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
                    if(title == "Select dictionaries") {
                        setDictionaryActivity();
                    }
                };

            };

            LookUp.Click += ( sender, eventArgs) => LookUpWord ();




        }

        private void setDictionaryActivity() {

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DictionarySelectionActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);

        }



        private void LookUpWord() {

            String inp = Input.Text;
            if( inp != "") {
                client.SendGetRequest("http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx", "Define", "word", inp);
            }
        }

        public void showDef(XmlDocument doc) {
            Words.Clear();
            XmlNodeList dlist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Definition");
            for(int i=0;i!=dlist.Count;i++) {
                Word w = new Word();
                w.dictionary = dlist.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).LastChild.InnerText;
                w.description = dlist.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText;
                Words.Add(w);
            }

            WordView.Adapter = new WordAdapter(this, Words);
        }

        protected override void OnPause() {
            base.OnPause ();
        }

        protected override void OnResume() {
            LookUpWord ();
            base.OnResume ();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Consider moving over from `HttpWebRequest` to `HttpClient`. You find an example here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/
Many people have problems with `HttpWebRequest` in conjunction with Xamarin.

Comment: have a look at the xamarin website's example - [Consuming SOAP Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/)